# Integration by completing the square

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to complete the square on the following integral.  Once this is done apparently I will be able to use on of the integration tables in the back of my book.

$\int x  \sqrt{x^2 + 6x +3} dx $

This is what I have come up with so far:

$\int x \sqrt{(x+3)^2 -6}  $

I really am at a loss.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please LaTeXify this question then it will be more appealing to answer! ;)

Comment: I would but I have no idea how to do that.  I have been trying to figure out how but I am not very computer savoy.

Comment: Note that $(x+3)^2$ is not the same as $x^2+3^2$, so your integral after substituting $u=x^2+3^2$ is not correct.

Comment: The following does not hold for all real $x$: $x^2+3^2=(x+3)^2$ hence you can't replace $(x+3)^2$ with $u$.

Comment: Thank you.  I had a little voice in my head saying something was wrong.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=x+3 \implies x=u-3, dx=du$:$$\int x\sqrt{(x+3)^2-6}dx=\int (u-3)\sqrt{u^2-6} du$$Integrating the integral gives:
$$\int u\sqrt{u^2-6}du-\int 3\sqrt{u^2-6} du=\frac{(u^2-6)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}-3\left(\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-6}}{2}-3\ln\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-6}\right)\right)$$In terms of $x$:$$\int x\sqrt{(x+3)^2-6}dx=$$$$\frac{((x+3)^2-6)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}-3\left(\frac{(x+3)\sqrt{(x+3)^2-6}}{2}-3\ln\left(x+3+\sqrt{(x+3)^2-6}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ I= \int x \sqrt {x^2 +6x +3} dx $$
This is best done by substitution.
$$I= \int x \sqrt {(x+3)^2-6} dx \\ x+3= \sqrt 6 \sec \theta \implies dx=\sqrt 6 \sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta$$
$$ \therefore I= \sqrt 6 \int \sec \theta \tan \theta ( \sqrt 6 \sec \theta -3) \sqrt {6( \sec^2 \theta -1)}  \\ I=6 \int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta ( \sqrt 6 \sec \theta -3)d \theta \\ I=6 \sqrt6 \int \sec^2 \theta \tan^2 \theta d\theta-18\int \sec  \theta \tan^2 \theta d \theta \\ \therefore I= 2 \sqrt6 \tan^3 \theta - 18\int \sec^3 \theta d \theta + 18\int \sec \theta d \theta \\ I =2 \sqrt6 \tan^3 \theta -9 \sec \theta \tan \theta +9 \ln | \sec \theta + \tan \theta | +C$$

Unless I screwed up the algebra I think this is correct. It could also be done using the substitution $ u=x^2+6x+3 $ and evaluating $\int \sqrt {x^2+6x+3} dx$.

Comment: Thanks however I have to solve this problem using completing the square.  The table that I believe I need to get to is                                        ∫u sqrt (u+ bu) du

Comment: Completing the square took place in the second line. The subsequent trig sub is the "staple method" to do these problems. I would only rely on those tables in the back of the book IF you can actually prove those standard integrals...

Answer (score 1):

Method using only completing the square:

Set up for substitution: $$ I= \int x \sqrt {(x+3)^2-6} dx= \int (x+3)\sqrt {(x+3)^2-6}dx -3\int\sqrt {(x+3)^2-6}dx$$

Substitute: $$u^2=(x+3)^2-6 \implies udu=(x+3)dx \\ \sqrt 6 v=x+3 \implies \sqrt 6 dv=dx$$

$$ \therefore I=\int u^2 du -18 \int \sqrt {v^2-1}dv $$

These are both elementary integrals.

This integral can also be done by parts... so many different methods.